# Can I say "She is too busy so that ..."?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction

I'm Japanese and I've already learned these two constructions.

> She is too busy to go to the party.
> She is so busy that she can't go to the party.

I've learned that they mean almost the same thing.
And I know "so that" can also be used like this.

> I didn't eat breakfast today so that I'm hungry now.

Then I have a question.
Can I say these?

> She is too busy so that she can't go to the party.
> She is so busy so that she can't go to the party.

Comment: No. The expression is _too busy to [do something]_. It's incorrect to repeat _so_ in the second sentence.

Comment: No, you *can't* say *She is too busy so that she can't go.* You have to say *She is too busy **to go***. OR *She is **so** busy **that** she **can't** go.*

Comment: "I didn't eat breakfast today so that I'm hungry now" sounds odd to me: "so that" would typically indicate an intention or purpose, e.g. "I didn't eat breakfast today so that I can stuff myself at the buffet lunch" or "I didn't eat breakfast today so that I can save money". It's a bit too formal for speech though.

Comment: Is "The roof had fallen in, so that the cottage was not habitable." also incorrect ? The most popular internet English-Japanese dictionary says this is correct. "so that" can mean result, though "that" is often omitted in conversation. https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/so+that

Comment: @Chance It's definitely not correct. You can omit the 'that' in 'so that', but not every instance of 'so' can have 'that' added. 'So that the cottage was not habitable' would only make sense if you were doing something to intentionally make it uninhabitable for whatever reason. 'We smashed the roof in, so that the cottage would be uninhabitable.'

Comment: @Chance "so that" implies *intention*, to do something so that you can do something else implies that you do the first thing intending to do the second thing. If there's no intent, including when the subject isn't capable of thought (as in your example where a roof has fallen in), you just say "so" without a that.

Comment: @Chance - The issue with your sentence is not the use of *so that*.  The issue is with pairing *so that* with *too* or *so*.  Your *roof had fallen in* example is perfectly OK.  The standard structure for too is, *Too [adjective] to [verb].*  Too smart to fail.  Too entitled to care.  Too drunk to drive.  If there are usages of *too* that differ, I would be interested to know of them.

Comment: I've understood that "too adjective to, so that" and "so adjective so that" are incorrect. I have to understand which of **"so adjective that"**, **"so that"**,  **"so"** , **"too adjective to"*** can mean **result**, **intention**, **degree**. I would like  these 12 combination to be newly written or added.

Answer (score 5):

First, I'd like to point out a nuance to using "so that." It is used to indicate **intention**: you did something to achieve the desired effect.

- I didn't eat breakfast today, so I'm hungry now.

is just a statement of fact. 1) I did not eat breakfast. 2) As a result, I am now hungry.

- I didn't eat breakfast today so that I am hungry now.

means that you deliberately did not eat breakfast because you wanted to be hungry.

**So as to your question:**

> She is too busy so that she can't go to the party.

This is incorrect. In English, we don't use "too X ... that". It sounds wrong, even if it might be understandable. If we wanted to say this, we would say something like "She is too busy. She can't go to the party." We can connect these sentences with a number of **conjunctions**:

- She is too busy **and** (she) can't go to the party.
- She is too busy, **so** she can't go to the party.
- She is too busy; she can't go to the party.

Your second sentence is closer to correct, but still a bit odd:

> She is so busy so that she can't go to the party.

Since "so that" implies intention, this makes it sound like she has chosen to be so busy because she wanted an excuse to avoid the party. The most natural way of saying this would be to drop or move the "that":

- She is so busy, she can't go to the party.
- She is so busy that she can't go to the party.

(Finally, you might notice that grammatically, the construction of this sentence looks very similar to the three example sentences I gave above.)

頑張ってください！

**Edit: Which of "so adjective that", "so that", "so" , "too adjective to" can mean result, intention, or degree?** This is tricky to explain, because a lot of it can be context.

- ...so [adjective] that...
- ...too [adjective] to...

These mean both result **and** degree: the degree causes the result. "This is *so big that* I can't lift it" indicates the degree of size (very big!) but also the result (cannot be lifted). You could also say "This is *too big to* lift" and that would mean the same thing.

"So" on its own can mean any of the options. It's very similar to から (*kara*) in Japanese—it just shows that two ideas are connected. "I did not eat breakfast, so I'm hungry." does not imply intention. Part of the reason this does not imply intention is because it's describing things as simple cause-and-effect.

"So that" implies intent and shows that the outcome was expected. It's always used with a **modal verb**, such as "will", "can", or "could". They know what the result will be ahead of time, so by taking that action, they expect that result.

- "I didn't eat breakfast so that I *would be* hungry."
- "She's staying busy so that she *won't be asked* to go to the party."
- "He left a note so that they *could see* we needed milk."
- "I am here so that I can try out for the team."

Honestly though, in all these cases you can drop/ignore the "that". The sentences sound far more natural and have the same meaning. Technically, it might be slightly more informal, but I don't think anyone will notice or care, and it will avoid a number of potential problems.

Comment: 頑張ります！ Is "The roof had fallen in, so that the cottage was not habitable." also incorrect ? The most popular internet English-Japanese dictionary says this is correct. "so that" can mean result, though "that" is often omitted in conversation. https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/so+that

Comment: If the first part of the sentence results in or implies the second part, simply use "so."  If the first part of the sentence describes an action or situation that is intended to make the second part true, one may use "so that." For example, "He destroyed the cottage roof, so that no one could move in." But in general, simply using "so" without "that" will almost always be correct in either case.

Comment: As a born English speaker, who wasn't taught any grammar I like this board teaches me why what I do is done. as in the " 'so that' shows intent" Oh yes it does doesn't it :)

Comment: I've understood that "too adjective to, so that" and "so adjective so that" are incorrect. I have to understand which of **"so adjective that"**, **"so that"**, **"so"** , **"too adjective to"** can mean **result**, **intention**, **degree**. I'm afraid but could you add these 12 combination in your answer?

Comment: I've added some more examples and explanation. Generally, I'd recommend just using "so" instead of "so that", since it will avoid a lot of this confusion. "So that" is uncommon nowadays; I would really only expect to see it in very formal or technical settings (an academic paper, a technical manual, a field report, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

A. She is too busy to go to the party. CORRECT

B. She is so busy that she can't go to the party. CORRECT

C. I didn't eat breakfast today so that I'm hungry now. INCORRECT

C. CORRECTED: I didn't eat breakfast today so I'm hungry now.

D. She is too busy so that she can't go to the party. INCORRECT

D. CORRECTED: She is too busy so she can't go to the party.

E. She is so busy so that she can't go to the party. INCORRECT

E. CORRECTED: She is so busy that she can't go to the party.

Comment: Is "The roof had fallen in, so that the cottage was not habitable." also incorrect ? The most popular internet English-Japanese dictionary says this is correct. "so that" can mean result, though "that" is often omitted in conversation. https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/so+that

Comment: In my opinion, that construction is awkward. It confuses two meanings: _The roof had fallen in, so the cottage was not habitable_ uses _so_ to mean _therefore_. The given sentence uses _so that_ in a way similar to _such that_: it shows that the roof fell in enough to make it inhabitable. (That would be in comparison to a roof that might have slightly fallen in, but in a minor way, so that the cottage would still be habitable.)

Comment: Thank you. Now I know "so that" always means intention.I have to understand which of **"so adjective that"**, **"so that"**, **"so"** , **"too adjective to"** can mean **result**, **intention**, **degree**. I'm afraid but could you add these 12 combination in your answer?